# How to hide my login and password in the python script?

Tags: python, password-protection, password-encryption

How can i not show the login ID and password in the python script?

Is there any library or command can I hide those information?

For example:

login_id = "secret_id" instead of login_id = "ABC@gmail.com"

password = "secret_password" instead of password = "1234ABCD"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use environment variables to decouple credentials and other sensitive content from your Python scripts.

```py
import os

# Get environment variables
login_id = os.getenv('MY_LOGIN_ID')
password = os.environ.get('MY_PASSWORD')
```

You can configure this on OS level using

```sh
export MY_LOGIN_ID="my login"
export MY_PASSWORD="my password"
```

Comment: go to Mac terminal type .bash_profile ??

Answer (score 3):

Maybe put the information in a text file, and read the text file into your python script?

```
with open('credentials.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    login_id  = lines[0].strip()
    password = lines[1].strip()
```

With the id on line 1 of your text file and the password on line 2.